# How to change the column format "yyyy-mm-dd" to "mmm-yy" in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to change the format of column ENROLLED_ON "yyyy-mm-dd" to "mmm-yy". Please help.

```
ENROLLED_ON | ENROLLED_ON
------------| ------
yyyy-mm-dd  | mmm-yy
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(enrolled_on, '%b-%y') AS enrolled_on
  FROM my_table
;
```

For info on MySQL date and time functions and the `DATE_FORMAT` function in particular, please see: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual: 13.7 Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

```
update
table_name
set enrolled_on = DATE_FORMAT(enrolled_on,'%b-%Y');
```

This is an update query for your column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` option which is inbuilt keyword of MySQL. Use it as:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y')

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(column_name, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM tablename
```

or using this, you can get date in any format you want

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field, '%d/%m/%Y')
```